# How to display a form in Full Screen with the taskbar on top of the form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that i disabled the control box and the title and made the border style "None" which means i have a completely blank form and the start windows state is "Maximized", when i run the program the form doesn't have control box and title and that's what i want but the thing is just that it is on top of the taskbar which means that the user can't see the taskbar and i don't want that so can you help me to make the taskbar in front of the application?

this is my code

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MaximumSize = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the maximum size of the form:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  this.MaximumSize = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;
  this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

Comment: hi LarsTech, it does bring it to the front but it doesn`t fill the screen?

Comment: @Arter Are you saying you want the taskbar to overlap your form?

Comment: @LarsText No i want My form to be behind of the taskbar

Comment: @Arter Did you try the code?  Might be a language translation issue, but overlap means the TaskBar is sitting "over" the form.  The posted code only allows the size of the form to  reach the size of the screen, minus the area of the TaskBar, so the form and the TaskBar, in essence, share the screen together.

Comment: Yes i tried it and it looks like this [link](https://imgur.com/4BXrtZv). it bring the task bar to the front but it does not make it maximized even though i have made the Windows state to maximized

Comment: @Arter You should update your question with the code you are using to reproduce that.  My screen does not look like that.

Comment: @LarsTeck, Thanks it appears that the border style was sizeable but now i changed it to None, Thanks a lor.